# scrollLeft javaScript horizontal scroll issue

Tags: javascript, html

Well I have a horizontal website that scrolls left.

I'm trying to get the navigation which is fixed to the top to scroll horizontally to each nav ID's anchor tag.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8baq/) for the file.

The code snippet is as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    $('.scrollPage').click(function() {
        var anchor = String($(this).attr("href")).replace("#","");
        var selector = 'div[name="' + anchor + '"]';
        var e = $(selector);
        var left = e.offset().left;
       $('html, body').animate({scrollLeft: left }, 800);
       return false;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background:url(images/fill.jpg) #74beb2 repeat scroll;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top:0;
    min-width:1140px;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding-top:0;
    height:768px;
}

#container {
    height:768px;
    width:17000px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}


nav {
    background:url(images/nav.png) no-repeat;
    height:80px;
    width:977px;
    position:fixed;
    margin-left:67px;
    margin-top:10px;
    z-index:100;
}

.navtype {
    width:845px;
    height:27px;
    margin-left:130px;
    margin-top:35px;    
}

/*NAV*/

/*-------------------------------------------------*/

/*SECTIONING*/

#sectionone {
    background:url(images/sectionone.jpg) no-repeat scroll;
    height:768px;
    width:1140px;
    float:left;
}

#sectiontwo {
    background:url(images/sectiontwo.jpg) no-repeat scroll;
    height:768px;
    width:622px;
    float:left;
}

#sectionthree {
    background:url(images/sectionthree.jpg) no-repeat scroll;
    height:768px;
    width:1140px;
    float:left;
}

#sectionfour {
    background:url(images/sectionfour.jpg) no-repeat scroll;
    width:1238px;
    height:768px;
    float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="container">
<nav><div class="navtype"><h2><a href="#sectionthree" class="scrollPage" name="about">ABOUT</a></h2><h2><a href="#sectionfive" class="scrollPage" name="films">FILMS</a></h2><h3><a href="mailto:info@staygoldfilmfestival.com">CONTACT</a></h3><h3><a href="#sectioneleven" class="scrollPage">LODGING</a></h3><h4><a href="#sectionthirteen" class="scrollPage">TICKETS</a></h4></div></nav>

<div id="sectionone">
</div>

<div id="sectiontwo">
</div>

<div id="sectionthree">
<div id="abouthead">
<div class="rule"></div>
<h1>About</h1>
<div class="rule"></div></div>
<div class="aboutbox">
</div>
<div id="abouttext"><p>The Stay Gold Movie Festival in Brooklyn, New York prides itself on bringing not only the classics when it comes to youth in revolt films, but also the spirit of the New York City life experience. The Films of The Wanderers, The Warriors, and The Outsiders are instant hits showing the comradery and friendship anyone would enjoy, not to mention the introduction of the good old "one-two" punch when it comes to taking out the pretty boys from the burbs. All in all if you want a heartfelt journey, filled with action, suspense, and good old greaer gang attitude, Stay Gold is the best for you.</p>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you include more code (perhaps a jsfiddle)? It is hard to understand exactly what you are trying to do with your selectors.

Comment: You code looks good. What happens when you execute this? Any error?

Comment: "Something's wrong." I love the details!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are handling the anchor correctly. Your selector is just putting in the `href` of the `<a>` and I don't think that works with jQuery. I put together a sample jsfiddle that does work, but I strip the `#` and use the `div[name="anchor"]` selector.

http://jsfiddle.net/pseudosavant/C9JSx/

Answer (score 0):

Also, you might wanna use a single tag so the action won't get caught/executed by both tags (html and body).